# javafx print for ListView

Tags: java, javafx

I have a javafx application and in the application I want to print a listview with the details on the list view. I have implemented the printJob and connected it to a button but it is still not printing anything. Below is my code

```
private void printOps(ActionEvent event){

        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
        if (job != null){
            Printer printer = job.getPrinter();
            PageLayout pageLayout = printer.createPageLayout(Paper.A4, PageOrientation.LANDSCAPE, Printer.MarginType.HARDWARE_MINIMUM);
            PrintResolution resolution =job.getJobSettings().getPrintResolution();

            boolean success = job.printPage(pageLayout, billingDataList);
            if (success){
                job.endJob();
            }
        }
```

the listview I want to print is `billingDataList` any help would be appreciated. further codes would be uploaded on request if needed.

Comment: Does your system show anything in the print queue?  Does your printer react in any way, such as a light coming on to indicate a print job in progress?

Comment: No. It’s not showing any dialogue to select additional settings.

Comment: Have you tried printing the value of `success`?

Comment: Yes it prints but doesn’t print the values on the listview

Comment: i have fixed to dialog issue. but it does not print the details in the listview. rather it prints `ù Z ○ M ڤซ ซ ù Z
￼￼￼￼Ć֝ẸزڤรẸ‹֝ฟز○ÈคỄรรỄ٣֝ ùײỄคỄรฮซỄủ֝
￼Ć ֝ Ẹ زڤ ร Ẹ ù Z ○ ì ù Z 7 9
￼Ć ֝ Ẹ زڤ ร Ẹ ÿ ฮ ڤ ײซ 7 / 7 ○ ز ữ ữ ữ ữ ữ ữ ữ
￼đฮฮฟ ○‹ 978*ญ8ญ97
￼Q ฮ ร ẫ Ễ ซ Ẹ ֝ Ẹ ڤฮ ร ○ ‹ 9 7
￼Ć ֝ Ẹ ٬ ฮ ซฮ ٣ Ỳ ○ ‹ 97
￼ÿ ڤẫ ز ؟ ซ ซ ֝ ร ز ฮ Ễ ẫ ○ ‹ 8 7
￼Z֝ Ẹ978○ ز*ญ8ญ97
￼ĚฮẸ֝ ซ○‹ 978*ญ8ญ97
￼Ěڤฟ978○ ز*ญ8ญ9798○9.○7=j7
￼`

Comment: Have you tried *showing* the value of `success`?  Such as with `System.out.println(success);`?

Comment: it comes back as true. It is printing but not printing the values on the ListView

Comment: it is like the printer is printing in a diffrent language that is not english

Comment: I’m starting to suspect a driver issue.  How did you add that output to your comment?  Did you print to a file?  If so, can you determine the type of that file?

Comment: No. Just normal printing. But with the printer settings I can save to pdf. I did that and it’s the same garbage that prints on paper that prints on the saved pdf